Finding an annual beta from daily data
In computing a CAPM analysis I have daily data for the market and security, but I have yearly per annum figures for the risk free rate. As such I am trying to annualise my market returns and my beta to be used in the calculation.
I have 10 years of daily data for both the market and the stock, I have calculated the daily geometric average of the market and have annualised it by putting it to the pwoer of 252 (the number of trading days per year).
I then found the daily covariance and the daily variance to calculate a daily beta. I then annualise the daily beta by multiplying by sqrt(252).
I'm not confident in this method and it gives me srtange results, please help any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Do you think beta grows indefinitely with the time period? This is what your annualization implies.

Another way to write Beta is: $$ \rho_{ij}\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_j} $$
Correlation is a dimensionless variable, and has no scale/annualisation factor. The two standard deviations in the fraction both scale with sqrt(T), so must cancel out, meaning beta is time invariant.

All good, but time invariant is not the same as independent of the period length / data frequency. Only the latter is directly relevant here.
